# git-svn hangs on clone

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

When attempting to clone n SVN repository, git-svn appears to search through the SVN history (I see `r[NNNNN] = [UUID] (refs/remotes/git-svn)` and a lot of `[A|M|D] <FilePath>/<FileName>` output) and then it hangs and never finishes. Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you waited long enough? I've had SVN clones take as long as 12 hours or more. I don't remember exactly, but I left it overnight and it was done in the morning. Network latency plays a huge part, as there are tons of (relatively) tiny files to be sent by SVN. Even with an extremely fast network, though, it can take hours for a decent-sized repo.

Comment: Do you see any indication of status (i.e., does it look like anything is happening)?

Comment: @Adam I never paid too much attention to it. I know at the very beginning of the clone, it has a message to the effect that it can be a very long process, and I think it might say that it could appear to hang. Try checking for CPU, file, and network activity.

Comment: I'm having this issue. The issue isn't that it's taking a long time, it's that there's no indication as to whether it is doing anything or not... I'm doing this on the machine where the SVN repo is hosted, so I would expect a fair bit of CPU power to be used up, but actually, the CPU is sitting at about 5% and no processes seem to really be doing anything. Apache is sitting at 0%. So, if this actually is doing something, there must be a lot of code that sleeps.